# Make PostConstruct of a controller of an included page to run

Tags: jsf

I have a template:

```
<html xmlns="blahblah">
<h:commandLink></h:commandLink>

 <ui:insert name="body" />
</html>
```

A page that uses this template:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="blahblah"
    template="/templates/template_main.xhtml">


    <ui:define name="body">
#{controller1.blahblah}
       </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Another page that uses this template:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="blahblah"
    template="/templates/template_main.xhtml">


    <ui:define name="body">
#{controller2.blahblah}
       </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

I want `controller1`'s or `controller2`'s `@PostConstruct` to run when i click the commandlink in template.

Or, if this is not possible, how can i get the info of current included page, and its controller bean to call its `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: This question makes no sense. The bean will already be autocreated by JSF whenever you reference it in EL. You don't need to manually create it. What exactly is your functional requirement and problem?

Comment: @BalusC, thanks for response. I have a language selection in the template on top of the page. I include some nested pages and I want the nested pages' PostConstruct to run when the language selection changes.

Comment: But if you just reference the bean by `#{bean}` in EL, it will already be autocreated. If the bean is request scoped, it will happen on every  request.

Comment: Can i get the page name or maybe some id of page which is included at that time?